# See in the console the history of a single file

Tags: git, git-bash

How can I see in the Git-Bash console the history with all the changes happened to a specific file in Git? With `git show [filename]` I can see only the last change. Is it possible? I think yes cause in Eclipse you can see the history of a file.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git log](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```sh
git log -p -- [filename]
```

Without `-p` you will get a list of commits, with `-p` you will also see the changes.